# Vue v-on:click.native in JSX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsx

How to write vue syntax `v-on:click.native` in JSX?

For example `v-on:click` in JSX is `onClick`.

Comment: so you want to use both react and vue?

Comment: No, I want to use render method in vue

Comment: can you provide some more details?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

Comment: ohhh anser was in docs: https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx  `nativeOnClick`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer was in the documentation for [**babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx**](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx) and it is `nativeOnClick`:

```
<el nativeOnClick={this.nativeOnClickHandler} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is wrong.

When using JSX (render function) you'd do this:

```
{
  components: {someComp},
  functional: true,
  render:function (h, c){
    return h(someComp, {
      nativeOn: {
        click: function(){
          //stuffs
        }
      },
    }, []);
  }
}
```

```
import SomeComp from '...'
return default {
  functional: true,
  render: (h, c) => <SomeComp nativeOn={{ click: e => { /* ... */} }} />
}
```

Comment: Nope. JSX and render function are not the same thing! You just show render function without JSX, and I was asking about JSX one. You can read about it more here: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/

Answer (score 0):

In vue/jsx latest version: https://github.com/vuejs/jsx

`v-on:click.native` => `vOn:click_native`